# How to use the Workbooks.add(template) to create a workbook in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to do the following:
In a template I have built in Excel 2016. When the template opens,the Workbook Open event is used to create a new workbook from this now open template and save it as a 'xlsm' file.I can't get the Workbooks.Add(template) to work. This is what I have attempted so far:

**dim wb as workbook**

**set wb=workbooks.add(Me)**  'Run-time error 1004' Application-defined or object defined error.

**set wb = workbooks.add("x:\Users\name\Documents\name of template.xltm")**
Where name is user name and template is valid name copied from File Explorer.
' Run-time error 1004...

'**Set wb = Workbooks.Add(Template:="C:\Users\Ed\Documents\Custom Office Templates\Itemized_Deduction.xltm")**   ' The exact path is shown in this attempt to show exactly what I was doing.  I had to use a _ between the Itemized and Deduction- the compiler did not like it with just a space as it is shown in the folder. The error was the same.

It would sure help if MS would give complete examples of the samples so we,the users of their fine products, could get it the first time.
I have been to this site, MS developer, Office Developer,and God knows where else and everything that was shown does not work.

Am I supposed to use a template of a workbook that is closed?

Can a XLTM template be used in this scenario?

Can someone show me how to use the .Add(template) please?

Comment: you should not use `Open Event` in template which creates new workbook using the same template. As a result you should have new workbook created which...creates new workbook which opens new one... and so on (infinitive loop). Your code with `Set wb = workbooks.add("full path name here to template")` is correct, possibly the `.xltm` file is not in that location.

Comment: The compiler would never complain about a space inside a quoted string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Roy and you are right in one of the points. The compiler will not allow the program to access the open file as the template.  I figured out what to do and will show it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had given it some thought after sleeping on it again and getting my head out of my *&^67!  I was making it way to complicated.  **All I had to do was do a Save As** on the template and the problem took care of itself.
Thanks for the help and support Roy.